# Negation of $X_1 = \{ x \in X: \exists y \in Y, (\phi^*)^{-1}\mu_x=\beta\mu_y+\mu,|\beta|>N,\mu\{y\}=0 \}.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, logic, definition, banach-spaces

Define the set $X_1 = \{ x \in X: \exists y \in Y, (\phi^*)^{-1}\mu_x=\beta\mu_y+\mu,|\beta|>N,\mu\{y\}=0 \}.$

If $x \not\in X_1,$ what do I have?

Am I right to say that for any $y \in Y,$ we have $(\phi^*)^{-1}\mu_x=\beta\mu_y+\mu$ with $|\beta|\leq N$ and $\mu\{y\} \neq 0$?

**More details:**

$X,Y$ are locally compact spaces with first countability. $C(X)$ denotes complex-valued continuous functions on $X.$

Let $\phi:C(X) \rightarrow C(Y)$ be a linear isomorphism and norm-increasing with $\|\phi\| < 2.$
Its adjoint is denoted as  $\phi^*:C(Y)^* \rightarrow C(X)^*.$

For any $x \in X,$ $\mu_x$ is a unit positive mass measure concentrated at $\{x\}$ only, that is, $\mu\{x \} =1$ and $\mu(X \setminus \{ x \}) = 0.$

Comment: Both the " , '' notation and the ":" mean logical AND. Use DeMorgan's law to write out the negation of that set. You will find it is easier than you think with this method.

Comment: @user400188: If $x\not\in X_1,$ then for all $y \in Y,$ we have the equation with $|\beta| \leq N$ or $\mu\{y\} \neq 0?$

Comment: That is a true statement, by which I mean it is not part of the set you defined; however it is not the entire negation.
Keep in mind that any of the original "," 's will become logical OR's, and that the negation of $\exists a [f(a)]$ is $\forall a \lnot[f(a)]$

Comment: @user400188: Didn't my previous answer include entire negation?

Comment: No, the whole negation would include every condition for which the an element would not be in the set $X_1$. For instance, it may be the case that $(ϕ^∗)^{−1}μ_x\neq βμ_y+μ$